# Velocity can't find resource

Tags: java, web-applications, velocity

Something is wrong and it is very frustrating. I read on velocity's homepage that when I run a webapp then some properties should be set. And I've done that but no matter what I do I keep getting the same error. 
This is where I set the props and use velocity

```
public class ConfirmationMailGenerator implements MailGenerator {

    private BasicUser user;
    private String htmlTemplate = "HTMLConfirmationMailTemplate.vsl";
    private String plainTemplate = "PlainConfirmationMailTemplate.vsl";

    public ConfirmationMailGenerator(BasicUser user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public StringWriter generateHTML() throws Exception {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("resource.loader", "wepapp");
        props.setProperty("webapp.resource.loader.class", "org.apache.velocity.tools.view.WebappResourceLoader");
        props.setProperty("webapp.resource.loader.path", "/WEB-INF/mailtemplates/");
        VelocityEngine engine = new VelocityEngine(props);
        VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();

        engine.init();

        Map map = createDataModel();
        context.put("user", map);

        Template template = engine.getTemplate(htmlTemplate);
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        template.merge(context, writer);

        return writer;
    }
...
}
```

The files is of course saved in /WEB-INF/mailtemplates/. 
If I use this I get this error:

```
SEVERE: ResourceManager : unable to find resource 'HTMLConfirmationMailTemplate.vsl' in any resource loader.
SEVERE: The log message is null.
```

Thank you for your time:)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You are using the Webapp resourceloader, which is intended for pages served by the Velocity Tools servlet.  (It requires some special initialization to find the root of the servlet context).

I recommend you use the ClasspathResourceLoader, then put the files into WEB-INF/classes, or elsewhere in your classpath.  This is really the most straight forward approach.

```
resource.loader = class
class.resource.loader.class = org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
```

More info is here:

https://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/runtime/resource/loader/ClasspathResourceLoader.html

Comment: @Will Glass please explain where to write your code

Comment: So you do need the 'class.' in front of the parameter.  I though that was a misprint 

Answer (score 2):

Will Glass answer is correct, but the configuration should be:

```
resource.loader = class
class.resource.loader.class = org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
```

Note the `class` at the beginning of the second line. See the links provided by him for more details!.

Note: Making an answer instead of a comment due to privileges.

Answer (score 1):

Velocity is probably using the class loader to find those files.  I'd recommend putting them in WEB-INF/classes, which is in the CLASSPATH by default.

Comment: I don't think this will work.  The WebappResourceLoader looks for resources in the root of the webapp, which it doesn't know since VelocityEngine was initialized without reference to the ServletContext.   You are thinking of the ClasspathResourceLoader -- see my response.

Answer (score 0):

I am fine it as follow,

In ***velocity.properties*** file

```
resource.loader=class, file
class.resource.loader.class=org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader
file.resource.loader.class=org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.FileResourceLoader
file.resource.loader.path=vm_template
runtime.log.logsystem.class=org.apache.velocity.runtime.log.SimpleLog4JLogSystem
runtime.log.logsystem.log4j.category=velocity
input.encoding=UTF-8
output.encoding=UTF-8
```

And at my java class

```
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.velocity.Template;
import org.apache.velocity.VelocityContext;
import org.apache.velocity.app.Velocity;
import org.apache.velocity.exception.ParseErrorException;
import org.apache.velocity.exception.ResourceNotFoundException;
import org.apache.velocity.tools.generic.DateTool;
import org.apache.velocity.tools.generic.EscapeTool;
import org.apache.velocity.tools.generic.LoopTool;
import org.apache.velocity.tools.generic.MathTool;
import org.apache.velocity.tools.generic.NumberTool;
import org.apache.velocity.tools.generic.SortTool;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

public class VelocitySupport implements InitializingBean {
private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(VelocitySupport.class);

@Autowired private Properties properties;

public final void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    location = location.replace("classpath:", "");
    Resource res = new ClassPathResource(location);

    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.load(res.getInputStream());

    String staticDir = System.getProperty("staticDir");
    String tempPath = prop.getProperty("file.resource.loader.path");
    tempPath = staticDir + "/" + tempPath;

    prop.setProperty("file.resource.loader.path", tempPath);
    Velocity.init(prop);
}

public static String merge(final String template, final VelocityContext vc) throws Exception {
    try {
        vc.put("date", new DateTool());
        vc.put("escape", new EscapeTool());
        vc.put("math", new MathTool());
        vc.put("number", new NumberTool());
        vc.put("iterate", new LoopTool());
        vc.put("sort", new SortTool());

        Template temp = Velocity.getTemplate(template);

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        temp.merge(vc, sw);
        sw.flush();

        return sw.toString();
    }
    catch (ResourceNotFoundException e) {
        log.error("", e);
        throw e;
    }
    catch (ParseErrorException e) {
        log.error("", e);
        throw e;
    }
}

private String location;

public final void setLocation(final String location) {
    this.location = location;
}
}
```

And insert VM arguments of project as follow..

```
-DstaticDir= "your directory for template path"
```

*That may be helpful for you*...

Answer (score 0):

For resolving this error
--WEB-INF/classes and all the JARs in WEB-INF/lib are in the CLASSPATH. Try moving your folder with the .vm files under WEB-INF/classes
--dont put the abolute path eg. if abc.vm file is in /public_html/WEB-INF folder then put path = "/public_html/WEB-INF/abc.vm" for velocity template path.