# Velocity engine unable to find resource

Tags: java, velocity

In my application user can receive email templates. I'm using `velocity engine` for sending emails. Email templates are located in the `WEB-INF/email_tempaltes/...` directory.

Here is my code:

```
String body = VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(velocityEngine, templateLocation, "UTF-8", model);
```

Where `templateLocation` is `String variable` which obvious looks something like this:

```
"/email_templates/request-feedback.vm"
```

Here is how I send mails:

```
private void sendEmail(final String toEmailAddresses, final String fromEmailAddress,
                           final String subject, final String attachmentPath,
                           final String attachmentName, final Mail mail, final String templateLocation) {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        MimeMessagePreparator preparator = new MimeMessagePreparator() {
            public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception {
                MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true, "UTF-8");
                message.setTo(toEmailAddresses);
                message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromEmailAddress));
                message.setSubject(subject);
                Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                model.put("phone", mail.getPhone());
                model.put("email", mail.getEmail());
                model.put("message", mail.getMessage());
                String body = VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(
                        velocityEngine, templateLocation, "UTF-8", model);
                message.setText(body, true);
                if (!StringUtils.isBlank(attachmentPath)) {
                    FileSystemResource file = new FileSystemResource(attachmentPath);
                    message.addAttachment(attachmentName, file);
                }
            }
        };
        this.mailSender.send(preparator);
    }
```

I tested email sending on my local machine and it works fine, but when i deployed it on the server i got an exception:

```
org.apache.velocity.exception.ResourceNotFoundException: Unable to find resource /email_templates/request-feedback.vm'
```

How can I fix it? Where should I store email templates? Thanks in advance!

**-----------EDITED:-----------**
I've created classes directory ander WEB-INF and have added my templates there.

And now I get template like this:

```
emailSender.sendEmail(mail.getEmail(), "info@somemail.com", "Your message was sent successfully", mail, "/classes/templates/request-sent-answer.vm");
```

And get the same error:

```
Could not prepare mail; nested exception is org.apache.velocity.exception.ResourceNotFoundException: Unable to find resource
```

Comment: Have you tried that? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443819/velocity-cant-find-resource

Comment: i've seen that, but i don't understand what should I add resource.loader = class
class.resource.loader.class = org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader

Comment: In a configuration file you can alos try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9051413/unable-to-find-velocity-template-resources

Comment: which configuration file? i don't have any configuration files

Comment: then create one for exemple velocity.properties and put it in web-inf/classes, by the way if you put your template directory in WEB-INF/classes, it will probably work by itself (as suggested in one linked answer)

Comment: alain.janinm please take a look at the edited part of my question above

Comment: WEB-INF/classes is the default classpath but if you have to create the classes directory yourself it's a pb and it's probably because the classpath is configured elsewhere. So instead of using WEB-INF/classes use the default directory where your compiled classes are stored.

Comment: solved problem moving email_templates directory to /java/resources foulder

Comment: Ok good. Then write it as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what mergeTemplateIntoString does, but another solution is to retrieve the template from the classpath and format it using MessageFormat.

```
String result;
final StringWriter templateData = new StringWriter();
final InputStream templateIn = YourClassName.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path);
  for(int b=templateIn.read(); b != -1; b=templateIn.read()){
     templateData.write(b);
  }
templateIn.close();
result = MessageFormat.format(templateData.toString(), arguments);
```